# Load different scripts based on viewport width

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to load different versions of modernizr, one for mobile and the other for all the rest.
For simplicity, let's just add the scripts based on 640px width. Both scripts need to go in the head.

Here is what I am trying:

```
if ( $(window).width() >640){
            window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/modernizr.custom.71422.js"><\/script>')
        }
        else{
            window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/modernizr.custom.js"><\/script>')
        }
```

This is wrapped in a script tag.

Comment: Is that it, or are you calling a function on window load?

Comment: @gtr1971 That is it, that snippet is wrapped inside script tag(in the Head).

Comment: Change your thinking. You don't want to load different scripts, you want to enable and disable the functionality that each script does. Loading the script based on window size is flawed because window size can change.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're writing a script tag within a script tag.  Try appending to the <head> instead of document.write:

```
$("head").append('<script src="js/modernizr.custom.71422.js"><\/script>');
```